# How can I use cross-env with expo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, expo

I have an expo app and I would like to use `cross-env` with expo.

I have changed the `start` script in package.json to `"cross-env LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS=TEST expo start"` but the environment variable is not defined once I run `npm start`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use `LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS` inside of your app? If so, you should follow this guide: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/

What you have done so far only sets the environment variable on the bundler process, it won't be available on your device where your app is running. The guide I linked to explains how to do this.

Comment: What if I need to set the environment variable using bash? You see, I'm trying to get the local ip address of the machine, which apparently is not constant. So I would like to do something like `cross-env LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS=$(command to get local ip address) ...`