# Forcing Expo To Update Environment Variable

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, expo

I have an Expo Application and I have an environment variable called `Local_IP_ADDRESS` that I'm using to make the app connect to the node server running on localhost, which makes development much faster (I used to have to deploy every time I make local changes to the server).

### SETUP

I have an expo app and I have followed the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/) to use environment variables using a dotenv file. I have installed the `inline-dotenv` babel plugin as well. I'm working on Expo Managed workflow.

### ISSUE

The issue is that Expo in a way caches `LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS` and since the value of that address changes often (it has already changed twice today), I would like a solution to either force Expo to get the new value or get the new value every time I run the app using a bash command who's result is stored and exported as an environment variable.

### WHAT I TRIED

I have tried something like `"cross-env LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS=$(command to get local ip address) expo start"` in `package.json` but it did not work ([see my stack overflow question on using cross-env with Expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72750472/how-can-i-use-cross-env-with-expo)). I have tried a similar thing but using `export` instead of `cross-env` and that did not work unfortunately. I have also tried to manually update the environment variable and then I used the command `expo r -c` which as far as I understand clears cache. That worked! Unfortunately, it took a long time to run the application.

### EXPECTED SOLUTION

The ideal solution is one that updates the local IP address every time the expo is started.

Comment: Are you working on Expo bare workflow?

Comment: @alexanderdavide I'm working on Expo Managed workflow.

Comment: Then I'd recommend using the dotenv file approach [from app.config.js](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/#from--appconfigjs) and accessing environment variables from [.extra](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/#using-app-manifest--extra). For me it works fine and this way you don't need `babel-plugin-inline-dotenv`.

Comment: That's what I did and it works, but I will have to go in and change the IP address once the router assigns a new one to my development machine. That is why I would like a way to load the environment variable into Expo using bash so that it is correct every time I run the app in development.

Comment: Sorry for my initial misunderstanding. I can now confirm that env variables are being cached. I found this [issue](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/issues/75) which contains various workarounds to consider.

Comment: Yes, I found the same issue as well.

Comment: I was able to set the local IP address in `app.config.js` using JS which apparently has access to the `os` package and then I injected the environment variable into Expo using the `extras` field and it works like a charm without using bash. But I still wonder if we can directly set an environment variable and the Expo app would see it after it's been bundled.